# curly braces in es6 arrow function for each

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

We create presentational component or stateless component like this

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   return(<div>my component</div>)
}
```

but I'd seen this

```
const MyComponent = () =>
   <div>
     <h1>head</h1>
     my component
   </div>
```

so now I'm confused when the braces is needed when using es6's arrow function.

This confused me on when rendering a list using map

shorter version

```
<div>
{map(o => 
   <div>{o.name}</div>
)}
</div>
```

longer version

```
<div>
    {map(o => {
     return(<div>{o.name}</div>)
     })}
</div>
```

Both are correct, but why write longer?

Comment: matter of opinion ... some people don't understand that there's a short form of `=>` if the function body is "simple"

Comment: The version without braces returns the statement following the `=>` operator. The version with braces executes the code block inside the braces and doesn't return anything automatically. People use the longer version when, for clarity, the code is long enough to require it.

Comment: This isn't (just) JavaScript. I presume it's React or something of that nature. Please add the appropriate tags.

Comment: @JLRishe sorry missed react

Comment: @JaromandaX one of the drawback of doing shorter version is that you can't debug with a console.log.

Comment: That would make it not a simple statement so I fail to see your point

Comment: `{ ... }` is a block. It allows you to perform multiple operations via statements. Implicit returns with `=> ...` only allow you to return an inline expression.

Comment: although, @estherJoo `() => console.log('debugging') || (<div>{o.name}</div>)` or `() => (console.log('debugging'), <div>{o.name}</div>)` could work :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{map(o => // without curly brackets 
   <div>{o.name}</div> // this will be returned implicitly
)}

{map(o => { // with curly brackets
    return <div>{o.name}</div> // you need to return explicitly
    } 
)}
```

If you do curly brackets ,
You have to explicilty return the data ,

> When to use which one?

When you have mutliple line of execution you need to do curly brackets and return from it

But if you have single line of execution, that you need to return , then there is no need of curly brackets and return , it will return implicitly.

> Same as If condition

```
if(true)
    // do this for single line
else
    // do this for single line




if() {
    // do this for multiple line
} else {
    // do this for multiple line
}
```

Comment: the if else example helps, thanks

Comment: @estherJoo, yeah its pretty simple to understand with that :) , Glad that help .

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions work both way to provide you with a bit of versatility. Say you need to perform some logic inside your function before you return, in this case you would need to add curly braces, i.e say you need to extract the name of a list of users, but you want to append their title.

```
let users = [new User(), ... ];
//...

let withTitle = users.map(p => {
   const title = getTitle(p); // automagically returns Mr, Mrs, etc
   return `${title} ${p.fullName}`
});

// withTitle => ['Mr Ricky Bobby', 'Mr Ron Burgundy']
```

Now, you can declare a function that does the work for you, and use the shorthand version of the arrow function. like so.

```
const extractWithTitle: (user) => {
   const title = getTitle(p); // automagically returns Mr, Mrs, etc
   return `${title} ${p.fullName}`
}

let withTitle = users.map(p => extractWithTitle(p));
// withTitle => ['Mr Ricky Bobby', 'Mr Ron Burgundy']
```

Now, an even shorter way to approach this would be to pass a reference to the function.

```
users.map(extractWithTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Both are correct, but why write longer?

You basically need to use the longer version if you need to add more sentences in you arrow function other than the `jsx` component.

E.g.

```
<div>
    {map(o => {
       const name = "My name is: " + o.name;
       return(<div>{name}</div>)
     })}
</div>
```

Otherwise, you may use the short version.